# If PQis a focal chord, show that the interval RU is parallel to the axis of the parabola.

Tags: functions, parametric

[image]

For part (c) of question thirteen am I only required to find the gradient of RU and prove that is it zero? This is how I have interpreted this question.

ANY help on the matter is much appreciated thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint...The focal chord property is $pq=-1$, whereupon you can calculate the gradient of $RU$...